# Swift: SegmentedControl in NavBar with Small TitleView

Tags: swift

I am attempting to include a segmentedControl on my navBar that looks like this:
[image]

The idea here is that the text "fetching..." is a small titleView. However, my current implementation would result in the text "fetching..." on the lower side like so:
[image]

I implement large titles so that I can get two "rows" on the navBar, else the word "fetching..." will be hidden behind the segmentedControl.

Code:

```
let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let items = ["Now","In 15 mins", "In 1 hour"]
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    return sc
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl

}
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `customView` that holds all the `views` you want to show in the `navigation bar` and set that view as `titleView` like below,

```
let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let items = ["Now","In 15 mins", "In 1 hour"]
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return sc
  }()

let fetchingLabel: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
       label.text = "Fetching..."
       return label
  }()
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250))
    customView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    customView.addSubview(fetchingLabel)

    fetchingLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60)
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width * 0.75, height: 30)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    navigationItem.titleView = customView
```

This should give you below result. You can play with the values to do what you want.

[image]